# Is there any evidence that Quirrell was a Death Eater?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

Considering events happening in the first book, can Quirrell be considered a Death Eater?

Comment: What "circumstances" do you mean? Do you mean that he was possessed by Baddy McBadguy? Or that he actively sought out the Dark Lord and it into his favours?

Comment: @Mooz More like events, that happened in the first book. Would those be enough for Quirrell to be considered DE?

Comment: Quirinus Quirrell was loyal to Voldemort, but he was not officially made a Death Eater as the organisation was inactive during Voldemort's years of disembodiment.

Comment: This question is rather subjective and opinion based. People could defend opinions that Quirrell was a DeathEater, while others could equally defend the notion that he was not. You can rewrite the question to "Is there any evidence that says Quirrell was a DeathEater?" That makes the question more objective.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Quirrell probably wouldn't be considered a Death Eater, just an ally.**

Not all of the Dark Lord's allies are considered Death Eaters. Willingly supporting him doesn't seem to be the only criterion for being considered a Death Eater. To put it more simply, the Death Eaters were generally the ones who were in Lord Voldemort's official army, and were the ones who'd fight alongside him.

However, Quirrell found the Dark Lord while he was traveling, and doesn't seem to have been made an official Death Eater during that time. The Dark Lord was likely more concerned with his plan for resurrection than making Quirrell a Death Eater. He certainly wasn't a known supporter of the Dark Lord before that, because Dumbledore was willing to hire him as a teacher. In addition, it's questionable if Quirrell would have even wanted to become a Death Eater. It's unclear how willing Quirrell truly was to support the Dark Lord. The Dark Lord would probably not actually make someone he's been forcing to serve him from the beginning an official Death Eater. Even Peter Pettigrew, arguably the least willing and most cowardly of the Death Eaters, probably had to agree to become one at some point, even if he later regretted it.

This quote implies that he wasn't necessarily willing to serve the Dark Lord at first:

> “He is with me wherever I go,’ said Quirrell quietly. ‘I met him when
>   I travelled around the world. A foolish young man I was then, full of
>   ridiculous ideas about good and evil. Lord Voldemort showed me how
>   wrong I was. There is no good and evil, there is only power, and those
>   too weak to seek it … Since then, I have served him faithfully,
>   although I have let him down many times. He has had to be very hard on
>   me.’ Quirrell shivered suddenly. ‘He does not forgive mistakes easily.
>   When I failed to steal the Stone from Gringotts, he was most
>   displeased. He punished me … decided he would have to keep a closer
>   watch on me …”

However, the Dark Lord does refer to him as faithful, although that may be a natural effect of being possessed by the Dark Lord for such a long time, or possibly some form of mind control or weakening as well:

> “See what I have become?’ the face said. ‘Mere shadow and vapour … I
>   have 
>   form only when I can share another’s body … but there have always been
>   those willing to let me into their hearts and minds … Unicorn blood
>   has strengthened me, these past weeks … you saw faithful Quirrell
>   drinking it for me in the Forest … and once I have the Elixir of Life,
>   I will be able to create a body of my own … Now … why don’t you give
>   me that Stone in your pocket?”

Narcissa supported him, up until she decided her son was more important than the Dark Lord, but she was never considered a Death Eater. However, she did help him in some ways, like letting Malfoy Manor be used as the Death Eaters' headquarters. She doesn't do as much as Quirrell, but she's still an ally of the Dark Lord at first.

There are other criteria as well, Death Eaters can be half-bloods or even mudbloods, but there are no non-humans who are known to have been Death Eaters. Fenrir Greyback was willing to support him, as were other werewolves, giants, and the Dementors, but none of them would be considered Death Eaters.

Quirrell was more of a tool, a vessel for the Dark Lord to use while regaining strength.

Comment: Narcissa wasn't an official Death Eater?

Comment: More of a puppet, as he was possessed (or manipulated) by Voldemort.

Comment: puppet ⊂ tool, probably

Comment: I think you need to provide some evidence that Narcissa Malfoy wasn't a Death Eater. She was present in what very much appeared to be "Death Eater only" meetings with Voldemort at Malfoy Manor.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, Narcissa wasn't actually a Death Eater. She was present at the meetings because they were held in her house, and since at that point she had 3 Death Eaters in her family she would have been considered fairly trustworthy. There are two answers on this question, and if you believe JKR, there's a quote by her stating that Narcissa wasn't a Death Eater: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78731/was-narcissa-malfoy-a-death-eater/156533#156533

Comment: "It's unclear how willing Quirrell truly was to support the Dark Lord." Except every quote cited clearly indicates Quirrell was a willing, faithful servant. Is there anything explicitly stating he wasn't acting of his own free will?

Comment: @talrnu This quote implies that he wasn't necessarily willing at first and he only became faithful as the Dark Lord gained greater influence and control over him:  *‘I met him when I travelled around the world. A foolish young man I was then, full of ridiculous ideas about good and evil. Lord Voldemort showed me how wrong I was.’* It suggests that Quirrell may have found the Dark Lord by accident, and only began serving him as he was influenced into it, growing more willing as the Dark Lord's power over him grew stronger. It doesn't rule out him serving willingly but it may indicate he didn't.

Comment: @talrnu This one implies that his continued service may also be out of fear: *‘Since then, I have served him faithfully, although I have let him down many times. He has had to be very hard on me.’ Quirrell shivered suddenly. ‘He does not forgive mistakes easily. When I failed to steal the Stone from Gringotts, he was most displeased. He punished me … decided he would have to keep a closer watch on me …’* He doesn't have any other option but to seem as faithful as possible, since the Dark Lord is possessing him and can surely make him suffer if he fails. He can't show doubt in the Dark Lord.

Comment: @Bellatrix I stand by my observation that these quotes don't imply any involuntary action, though I do agree that the context they're taken from (Quirrell under Voldemort's watchful eye) suggests the possibility that he's under duress as he says them. Then again, the narrator doesn't observe any of the symptoms of duress or mind control (or, admittedly, any lack of these), so ultimately assuming anything of the sort is pure speculation. Brainwashing, perhaps, but that's not exactly involuntary.

Comment: @talrnu That's why I don't make a definitive conclusion either way. It's unclear, so  I don't want to conclusively say that he either was or wasn't willing. I provide the evidence and supporting points for both in my answer, and I say that he wasn't necessarily willing, but I don't attempt to make a definitive conclusion.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not.

1) Voldemort was in a very weak state at this time, and cursing (or blessing, depending on your viewpoint) someone with a Dark Mark would probably require strength. Which he'd want to conserve.

2) Quirrell was hinted to be reluctant to follow through with what Voldemort was asking of him. He was a Ravenclaw, not a Slytherin. I think he was only in it for the knowledge, and got in over in his head. Or maybe he just cracked under the pressure. Either way, he didn't seem to be great Death Eater material, and Voldemort didn't need him to be one to control him. He was already living in the back of his head; a Dark Mark would be overkill.

He could be considered a Death Eater in spirit, but I don't think he actually was one.

Comment: Makes sense, but where does it say he was Ravenclaw?

Comment: Only on Pottermore:   https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/quirinus-quirrell